# Aggregating by category & obtaining conditional counts

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

My temporary able has 3 columns where an individual is unique by Category ID AND Customer ID (i.e. there can be multiple identical Customer IDs across categories; customer ID is not unique).

| Category ID | Customer ID | Number of Purchases |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | A | 4 |
| X | B | 10 |
| X | C | 2 |
| Y | A | 2 |
| Y | E | 6 |
| Z | A | 11 |
| Z | C | 5 |
| Z | D | 10 |

The output table I am looking for is basically 4 columns: **grouped by category ID** identifying **total number of customers who have at least 1 purchases**, **customers who have at least 10 purchases** as well as **total purchases across all customers within that category**. The output table would look like this:

| Category_ID | Total_Customers_1 | Total_Customers_10 | Total_Purchases |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | 3 | 1 | 16 |
| Y | 2 | 1 | 8 |
| Z | 3 | 2 | 26 |

When I input the following code, I get the correct total purchases column per category but the total number of customers who had at least 3 purchases per category is incorrect as the aggregates are identical across all categories.

How should I proceed? Thank you for your help.

Update: I forgot to add my code:

```
SELECT table.categoryID AS Category_ID 
        (SELECT COUNT (table.customerID) 
        FROM table 
        WHERE table.purchases >=1) AS Total_Customers_1, 
        (SELECT COUNT (table.customerID) 
        FROM table 
        WHERE table.purchases >=10) AS Total_Customers_10, 
    SUM (table.purchases) AS Total_Purchases, 
FROM table 
GROUP BY Category_ID, Total_Customers_1, Total_Customers_10,
```

(P.S When I try to just GROUP BY Category_ID, I get an ERROR that syntax is incorrect because I have sub-queries in my SELECT statement.

Comment: You forgot to post the "following code"

Comment: Please format your code to note just be a single line. New lines and indents matter for readability.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation.

```
SELECT
  category_id,
  COUNT(*) AS total_customers_1,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN purchases >= 10 THEN customer_id END) AS total_customers_10,
  SUM(purchases)   AS total_purchases
FROM
  yourTable
GROUP BY
  category_id
```

I used the DISTINCT as defensive programming, but if a customer id only exists once in any given category, it's not required.

Notes:

- CASE expressions without an ELSE clause default to ELSE NULL
- Aggregates, such as COUNT(), exclude NULLs